# Css Hover Effect with Jquery

Tags: jquery, hover

`.parent:hover .child`

I'm trying to do this exact thing but only with jQuery.

Comment: `$('.parent').on('hover', function() { $(this).find('.child').doSomething(); });`. If all you want to do is change the styling of `.child` on hover of the parent, then this should be done in CSS, not JS

Comment: A close button for a hover effect seems a little redundant.

Comment: What I'm basically trying to accomplish is to have portfolio grid with the grid columns having two overlapping divs, one which is  for the background and one which is the info text which appears over the background div on hover. And I want to be able to close the hover over info div which appears when im hover the column by clicking on close button on the top right.

Comment: I agree its little redundant but I still want to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code snippet for your concern. You can use the hover event with two functions as an argument.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".parent").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("hover");
  },function(){
  $(this).removeClass("hover");
  });
})
```

```css
.parent{
height:100px; 
width:200px;
background-color:#F00;
} 
.parent .child{
height:60px; 
width:160px;
background-color:#0F0;
margin:20px;
}
.parent.hover .child{
background-color:#00F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
</div>
<div>
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed :)

Comment: Welcome, pleased to help you.. if you like answer please mark as correct and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use CSS over jquery ( if possible) otherwise you can use something like this

```
$("div.myclass").hover(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color","red")
});
```

You can change your selector as per your need.

If you want to use this hover effect to multiple classes, you can use it like this

```
$(".myclass, .myclass2").hover(function(e) { 
    $(this).css("background-color",e.type === "mouseenter"?"red":"transparent") 
})
```

[JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/TpX8S/1/)

Comment: Note that this isn't quite the same as the CSS selector in the question.